# SSRS Microsoft Reporting: Conditional grouping

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, conditional-statements, grouping, rdlc

Is it possible to make a group and sort conditional? If so, is it possible to somehow do this based on the value of a textbox item?

I thought I could just set the Expression of the group and sort to something like `=IIF(ReportItems!TheTextBox.Value = 0, 0, Fields!FieldName.Value)`, which would be perfect, but it doesn't allow me to use ReportItems in group or sort expressions =(

Really don't want to make two reports whenever I need that feature... hope someone can shed some light on this!

Using:

- Microsoft reporting services
- Report viewer with local processing

Comment: why don't you use a report parameter or the result dataset ?

Comment: It is a sub-report, so I can't use report parameters. So I have a result dataset working as a.. boolean report parameter collection, kind of. The textbox gets the value 0 if a parameter does not exist in that collection, and 1 if it does. works greatly for other things =)

Answer (score 1):

**edit**

> It is a sub-report, so I can't use
>   report parameters.

you can. see [How to: Add a Subreport and Parameters (Reporting Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348.aspx)
**/edit**

Try to check this report parameter collection in grouping expression. Something like:

```
=IIF(Parameters!<ParameterName>.Count = 0, 0, Fields!FieldName.Value)
```

See [Using Parameters Collection References in Expressions (Reporting Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337293.aspx)

Comment: I can't use report parameters in a sub-report without defining them in the master report and also specify which ones to "send down" to the sub-report. And I just don't want to do that really.

Comment: Not because I'm just difficult, but because the master report works as a master template for many reports, taking care of page numbers and various information that must be on every report. Also helps to make them all look the same.